# How to find the user is idle in certain location for 10 minutes in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I am using map with finding route, if user starts moving the location updates using the following method,

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Now if user is stop moving and remains in the same place for 10 minutes i want to show alert. So how to check 10 minute interval in the above method? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I would advise you to use `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` because  `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` was deprecated in iOS 6.0. And then in this method you can use:

```
 (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
 { 
   //Cancel perform requests previously 
   //  registered with the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: 

  [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
  //Register new perform request to fire after 10 minutes
  [self performSelector:@selector(showAlertOnIdle) withObject:nil afterDelay:600.0];
 }
```

This method is called every time new location data is availbale in `locations` array. So   if user will constantly move selector will never fire because of previous cancellation and will be called only if within 10 minutes interval there are no new location data.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the replay. But i want user remains stable in a location for 10 min only i should show alert, else shouldnt show alert.. So how to check user stay in a same place for 10 min.

Comment: @Surfer No, you can read `performSelector:afterDelay` docs. It will be called only once 10 minutes after last location update and then next time when `didUpdateLocations` delegate will be called again.

Comment: if i am moving state, also message will show after 10 min right?

Comment: You can use `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:]` or `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:]` in the beginning this will invalidate selector calling request.

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov http://stackoverflow.com/q/40610320/2522603 please have a look, i used ur solution but it gives alert after ten minute if device is moving too

Answer (score 1):

Place a `NSTimer` object in your class, let's say `idleTimer` like this:

```
NSTimer *idleTimer;
```

As @Alexander suggested, use `didUpdateLocations` like this:

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    //dismiss already running timer as location has been updated..
    if (idleTimer) {
        [idleTimer invalidate];
        idleTimer = nil;
    }

    //start timer
    idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600 target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

and make a `idleTimerFired`, method to show alert:

```
- (void)idleTimerFired {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: implement `UIAlertViewDelegate`'s method `clickedButtonAtIndex`

Comment: Or set `alertView`'s delegate `nil`